# Excel Macro to add HTML Bold tags 'breaks' at 240 character mark

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA macro that runs on a cell to add HTML Bolding tags around bolded text (and maintain the bolded formatting visually). This works well though I've found that for cells with a length greater than 240 characters, it stops working reliably.

I am not well versed in Excel VBA. I'm trying to learn and figure out, but can't see what is incorrect.

```
Sub Tester()
    AddTags Range("A1")
End Sub

Sub AddTags(c As Range)

  Dim p As Long, isB As Boolean
  Do
      p = p + 1
      If p > Len(c.Value) Then Exit Do

      If c.Characters(p, 1).Font.Bold And Not isB Then
          'entering a bolded section
          c.Characters(p, 0).Insert "<b>"
          c.Characters(p, 3).Font.Bold = True
          isB = True
          p = p + 3 'skip the tag you just added
      ElseIf Not c.Characters(p, 1).Font.Bold And isB Then
          'leaving a bolded section
          c.Characters(p, 0).Insert "</b>"
          c.Characters(p, 4).Font.Bold = True
          isB = False
          p = p + 4 'skip the tag you just added
      End If
  Loop
  'close any open tag
  If isB Then c.Characters(p, 0).Insert "</b>"
End Sub
```

Example of what I mean by "break": It will add the beginning `<b>` code where applicable, however instead of closing it with `</b>`, it will change the formatting of the text of the next four characters to bold. In other words, if there is a phrase "**Example** sentence here" after running the macro it would appear as "`<b>`**Example sen**tence here".
As I've said, this consistently breaks in cell lengths over 240 characters. This does not appear to be an issue in cell lengths LESS than 240 characters.

Expected result would be "`<b>`**Example`</b>`** sentence here"

Comment: You are going to have all sorts of problems in Excel when the cell's value is going to exceed 255 characters. This is a very long standing problem.

Comment: Are you including the length of the new "<b>" ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's the 255 limit, as 240 + 2 <B> = 246 chars. ??

Comment: I've just run your code on a 240 string and it worked.

Comment: Yikes. Didn't realize that it was an issue with Excel and over 255 characters. If that is the case, I believe I can work around it. If this is a fundamental issue (and not a code issue) then at least I can stop scratching my head :)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I'm going to try on a few others specifically around the 255 mark and see if I can pinpoint when its an issue. Maybe it starts being a problem specifically at 251 (when adding 4 characters "<b>" would increment to 255). I don't have many cells in between 240-250 so I assumed it was at the 240 mark, my apologies! Doing more recon right now.

Comment: @louisepbaker I used `testing this out testing this out testing this out this out testing this out  this out testing this out testing this out testing this out testing this out testing this out testing this out testing this out testing this out testing this out `  with the first testing bold

Comment: Confirmed that it works until the NEW string (with added html tags) will exceed 255 characters. If the new string will have 256 characters or more, it does not add the tags and insteads just changes the visual formatting to bold.

Comment: Thank you @GSerg this is the correct answer